# Tensor expression in 'Tensor Calculus' by J.L. Synge and A. Schild (1979 Dover publication)

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I'm solving all the exercises  of 'Tensor Calculus' by J.L. Synge and A. Schild (1979 Dover publication) . Exercise 12. page 110 of the third chapter on 'Curvature' is stated as:

Prove that the quantities $$G^{mn}+ \frac{1}{2a}\frac{\delta^2}{\delta x^x \delta x^s}\left[ a \left( a^{mn}a^{rs}-a^{mr}a^{ns} \right)\right]$$ can be expressed in terms of the metric tensor and its first derivatives.

(For those not acquainted with the notation convention in this book: the $\delta$ are used for the absolute derivative of a tensor, $a^{ij}$ is the conjugate metric tensor with $a$ the determinant of the matrix containing the elements of the (covariant) metric tensor. And $G^{mn}$ is the contravariant form of the Einstein tensor.)

My question. Does someone know why the author chose this expression? Is it used somewhere in general relativity or physics in general? The pattern in the second term suggest remotely a connection with the Riemannian curvature ...

I ask this question here as the author's worked a lot around general relativity and gravitation.

Note: there must  be a typo error as $\delta x^x $ in $\frac{\delta^2}{\delta x^x \delta x^s}$ makes no sense. So I guess this must be  $\frac{\delta^2}{\delta x^r \delta x^s}$. Also, it seems odd to me that the authors use  the absolute derivative symbol  in this expression. That does not make sense to me and I suppose they mean the covariant derivative instead. So the expression (sorry, I use the notational convention of the book and not the more modern one with $\nabla$ or $;$) should be $G^{mn}+ \frac{1}{2a}\left[ a \left( a^{mn}a^{rs}-a^{mr}a^{ns} \right)\right]_{|rs}$. Am I right?

Comment: It is a typo. The $\delta x^x$ term needs a $r$ superscript.